Pinia query loses reactivity over fetch with useAsyncData
We got a service which fetch data from an api, populate the dedicated pinia-orm store, then return the result as an object containing the pinia-orm query result and metadata (page, totalItems...).
We then use useAsyncData to call this fetch method from our page.
I'm not sure if it's a misuse, a bug, or else, but if I only rely on useAsyncData to take care of the reactivity, this does not work. The only way I found so far is to wrap the fetch method into a computed ref, which result in an ugly result when used in setup scripts (data.value.value.items !)
If you take a look here :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-fqfni1?file=services%2Ffetcher.ts
You'll see the two returned collections, fetched via useAsyncData. Then if you click on the button to add a new record to the store, you'll see that only the second list get reactively updated.
Anyone could help me understand why?

I am not all too familiar with Pinia ORM but after a quick look at their docs it says this:

When querying the data from the store, in most cases, you want to query data inside the computed property. This way, when any data changes, the part of your application where you use those data gets updated reactively. It works as same as Pinia Getters.

So I suspect that is why. Hopefully, that answers your question.

Ok that's right, thanks, however I can not find a proper way to combine the use of useAsyncData and of the computed.
